# Using Eigen to solve a dense, constrained least squares fit

Tags: c++, optimization, eigen, least-squares

I need to solve a classic problem of the form Ax = b for a vector x that is of size 4. A is on the order of ~500 data points and thus is a dense 500x4 matrix.

Currently I can solve this using the normal equations described [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html) and it works fine however I would like to constrain one of my parameters in x to never be above a certain value.

Is there a good way to do this programmatically with Eigen?

Comment: This is pretty much an entirely different problem class and i don't expect eigen to support it (although i did not check). You would need to implement your own method. scipy (python) and matlab seems to use a ```Trust Region Reflective``` (imho non-trivial) algorithm or the ```Bounded-Variable Least-Squares algorithm``` (no idea how hard to implement). I also think you can solve this using a projected-gradient algorithm, but i don't have the time to implement this currently [huge script on the topic](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You can try my quadradic programming solver based on Eigen [there](https://gitlab.inria.fr/alta/alta/tree/master/external/quadprog++). You'll still have to form the normal equation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some **python-demo** (using numpy which is not that far away from Eigen) showing an **accelerated projected-gradient algorithm** for your kind of problem. Typically this approach is used for large-scale problems (where other algorithms incorporating second-order information might struggle), but it's also nice to implement.

This version, which is a small modification from some old code of mine is not the most simple approach which can be used, as we are using:

- acceleration / momentum (faster iteration)
- line-search (saves us some step-size tuning trouble)

You could remove the line-search and tune the step-size. Momentum is also not needed.

As i'm not doing much C++ right now, i don't think i will port this to Eigen. But i'm sure, that if you would wanto to port it, it's not that hard. Eigen should not be too different from numpy.

I did not measure the performance, but the results are calculated instantly (perceptually).

**Edit:** some non-scientific timings (more momentum; lesser tolerance than in following code):

`A=(500,4)`:

```
Solve non-bounded with scipys lsq_linear
used:  0.004898870004675975
cost :  244.58267993

Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with scipys lsq_linear
used:  0.005605718416479959
cost :  246.990611225

Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with accelerated projected gradient
early-stopping @ it:  3
used:  0.002282825315435914
cost:  246.990611225
```

`A=(50000, 500)`:

```
Solve non-bounded with scipys lsq_linear
used:  4.118898701951786 secs
cost :  24843.7115776

Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with scipys lsq_linear
used:  14.727660030288007 secs
cost :  25025.0328661

Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with accelerated projected gradient
early-stopping @ it:  14
used:  5.319953458329618 secs
cost:  25025.0330754
```

The basic idea is to use some gradient-descent-like algorithm, and project onto our constraints after each gradient-step. This approach is very powerful, if that projection can be done efficiently. Box-constraint-projections are simple!

[Page 4 in this pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/notes/nlp/gpa.pdf) shows you the box-constraint projection.

We just clip our solution-vector to `lower_bound, upper_bound`. Clipping in numpy is described as: *Given an interval, values outside the interval are clipped to the interval edges. For example, if an interval of [0, 1] is specified, values smaller than 0 become 0, and values larger than 1 become 1.*

It's an iterative-algorithm approximating the solution and i think every algorithm in use will be an iterated one.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import lsq_linear
np.random.seed(1)

A = np.random.normal(size=(500, 4))
b = np.random.normal(size=500)

""" Solve Ax=b
    ----------
"""
print('Solve non-bounded with scipys lsq_linear')
sol = lsq_linear(A, b)
print('Ax=b sol: ', sol['x'])
print('cost : ', sol['cost'])
print()

""" Solve Ax=b with box-constraints
    -------------------------------
"""
print('Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with scipys lsq_linear')
sol = lsq_linear(A, b, bounds=(0.001, 0.05))
print('Ax=b constrained sol: ', sol['x'])
print('cost : ', sol['cost'])
print()

""" Solve Ax=b with box-constraints using a projected gradient algorithm
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
def solve_pg(A, b, bounds=(-np.inf, np.inf), momentum=0.9, maxiter=1000):
    """ remarks:
            algorithm: accelerated projected gradient
            projection: proj onto box constraints
            line-search: armijo-rule along projection-arc (Bertsekas book)
            stopping-criterion: naive
            gradient-calculation: precomputes AtA
    """

    lb = np.empty(A.shape[1])
    ub = np.empty(A.shape[1])
    if len(bounds) == 2:
        # apply lb & ub to all variables
        lb = bounds[0]
        ub = bounds[1]
    else:
        # assume dimensions are ok
        lb = np.array(bounds[0])
        ub = np.array(bounds[1])

    M, N = A.shape
    x = np.zeros(N)

    AtA = A.T.dot(A)
    Atb = A.T.dot(b)

    stop_count = 0

    def gradient(x):
        return AtA.dot(x) - Atb

    def obj(x):
        return 0.5 * np.linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)**2

    it = 0
    while True:
        grad = gradient(x)

        # line search
        alpha = 1
        beta = 0.5
        sigma=1e-2
        old_obj = obj(x)
        while True:
            new_x = x - alpha * grad
            new_obj = obj(new_x)
            if old_obj - new_obj >= sigma * grad.dot(x - new_x):
                break
            else:
                alpha *= beta

        x_old = x[:]
        x = x - alpha*grad

        # projection
        np.clip(x, lb, ub, out=x)  # Projection onto box constraints
                                   # see SO-text
                                   # in-place clipping

        y = x + momentum * (x - x_old)

        if np.abs(old_obj - obj(x)) < 1e-2:
            stop_count += 1
        else:
            stop_count = 0

        if stop_count == 3:
            print('early-stopping @ it: ', it)
            return x

        it += 1

        if it == maxiter:
            return x

print('Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with accelerated projected gradient')
sol = solve_pg(A, b, bounds=(0.001, 0.05))
print(sol)
print('cost: ',  0.5 * (np.square(np.linalg.norm(A.dot(sol) - b))))
```

#### Output

```
Solve non-bounded with scipys lsq_linear
Ax=b sol:  [ 0.06627173 -0.06104991 -0.07010355  0.04024075]
cost :  244.58267993

Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with scipys lsq_linear
Ax=b constrained sol:  [ 0.05        0.001       0.001       0.03902291]
cost :  246.990611225

Solve bounded (0.001, 0.05) with accelerated projected gradient
early-stopping @ it:  3
[ 0.05        0.001       0.001       0.03902229]
cost:  246.990611225
```